# Converting numbers to text in such a way that they do not lose their function and still behave like numbers

Tags: python, text, type-conversion, numbers

is it possible to convert numbers to text in Python in such a way that they appear as text but still behave like numbers? Ideally without using lists. In the most simplistic way, for example: 1 + 1 = 2 to convert to one + one = two.

I tried for example the num2words library, but the result is always just a concatenation of text(oneone) instead of the result of the sum.
Thank you in advance for your answers and patience since I am still a newbie.

```
from random import randint
from num2words import num2words

score = 0
while score <= 10:
    num1 = randint(1,10)
    num2 = randint(1,10)
    qAns = num2words(num1) + num2words(num2)
    print("What is", num2words(num1),"plus" + num2words(num2))
    ans = input("type your answer: ")
    if ans == qAns:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        score = score - 1
    print(score)
```

Comment: You should add the code you've tried in your question as well

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, I added the code.

Comment: Why not just do `num2words(num1+num2)`

Comment: It is overkill here, but you can define a class of number-like objects whose string representations work as you want and which behave like ordinary numbers under +, *, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing if the `string` of the two random numbers equals the `string` of the input, you should first convert the user input to the appropriate type (`int`) and then make the correct `if` condition (`if num1 + num2 == ans`)

```py
from random import randint
from num2words import num2words

score = 0
while score <= 10:
    num1 = randint(1,10)
    num2 = randint(1,10)
    print(f"What is {num2words(num1)} plus {num2words(num2)}: ")
    ans = int(input("type your answer: ")) # Notice the int() wrapping the input()
    if num1 + num2 == ans:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        score = score - 1
    print(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a library which converts word to number and added to your code. Please see below:

```
from random import randint
from num2words import num2words
from text_to_num import text2num

def word_to_num_contertor(word, lang):
    num_result = text2num(word, lang)
    return num_result

score = 0
while score <= 10:
    num1 = randint(1,10)
    num2 = randint(1,10)
    print(f"What is {num2words(num1)} plus {num2words(num2)}: ")
    ans = input("type your answer: ") 
    if ans.isdigit(): # if the user type a digit as an answer, like 11.
        if num1 + num2 == int(ans):
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
            score = score - 1
    else: # if the user type a word as an answer, like eleven. 
        if num1 + num2 == word_to_num_contertor(ans, "en"):
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
            score = score - 1
    print(score)
```

So, as an answer, it can accept both 11 and eleven. Please see snapshot from the code.

[image]